# SAPUI5 VizFrames - Error: unknown type: ready

Tags: charts, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am developing a custom Fiori App which uses sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame for displaying charts (let's call this App-1). The app is deployed on Fiori Launchpad.

Upon first loading of App-1, charts work perfectly fine - it display and bind data correctly. But when I switch to App-2 from Fiori Launchpad, then go back to App-1, the VizFrames displays an error message "Error: unknown type: ready"

[image]

I checked the data being binded on the charts, and there seems to be no issue with the data, and there is also no error message on devtools.

My App-2 calls `sap.ui.loader.config` before declaring the UIComponent's list of dependencies in my `Component.js`

[image]

Then I load and consume the library on App-2:
[image]

What is the possible reason why the VizFrames data do not appear upon loading the App-1 for the second time?